# Stack trace of go routine from imported package?

Tags: go

How to obtain the stack trace of the last (ideally of all) go routine (the app has multiple go routines) which panicked and recovered and logged only a not much descriptive error message? I don't know which routine recovered. Also, please keep in mind that I will not alter the code of any imported package. This panic happened in some of the imported packages which creates multiple go routines so I need a way to grab the stack trace of the last recovered routine in order to find where it panic.

Comment: Why can't you alter the package code? You have the code if you can build the program.

Comment: I will try, but I am asking for a more convenient way to get the trace from the main program :)

Comment: If the code recovers from a panic, you don't see the panic. You could try setting a breakpoint in a debugger, but given the state of debuggers it's probably just much faster to comment out the `recover` and get a stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: **Not possible** but there are **exceptions**.

Golang has a few stack control methods and types.

You can control the stack levels with [runtime/debug/SetTraceback](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#SetTraceback)

`func SetTraceback(level string)`

> SetTraceback sets the amount of detail printed by the runtime
>   inthe traceback it prints before exiting due to an
>   unrecovered panic or an internal runtime error.
>   The level argument takes the same values as the GOTRACEBACK
>   environment variable. For example, SetTraceback("all") ensure 
>   that the program prints all goroutines when it crashes.
>   See the package runtime documentation for details. If
>   SetTraceback is called with a level lower than that of the
>   environment variable, the call is ignored.

You can also print the stack strace with [runtime/debug/Stack](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#Stack)

`func Stack() []byte`

> Stack returns a formatted stack trace of the goroutine that calls it. It  calls runtime.Stack with a large enough buffer to capture the entire trace.

Also you need to understand how the Built-in funct `recover` works.

> The recover built-in function allows a program to manage behavior of a
>   panicking goroutine. Executing a call to recover inside a deferred
>   function (but not any function called by it) stops the panicking sequence
>   by restoring normal execution and retrieves the error value passed to the
>   call of panic. If recover is called outside the deferred function it will
>   not stop a panicking sequence. In this case, or when the goroutine is not
>   panicking, or if the argument supplied to panic was nil, recover returns
>   nil. Thus the return value from recover reports whether the goroutine is
>   panicking.

`func recover() interface{}`

#### Working Example

This example assumes that the package does not call recover (detailed in another section).

[Golang Playground Link](https://play.golang.org/p/K1kS6WzsKf)

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "errors"
    "runtime/debug"
    "time"
)

func f2() {
    panic(errors.New("oops")) // line 11
}

func f1() {
    f2() // line 15
}

func main() {
    defer func() {
        if e := recover(); e != nil {
            log.Printf("%s: %s", e, debug.Stack()) // line 20
        }
    }()

    go f1() // line 25

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
}
```

#### If package calls recover

If the code is recovering from the panic you need to use a debugger or remove the `recover` to understand what is going on as seen on the example below which demonstrate that recovered panics can not be "recovered" again.

[Golang Playground Link](https://play.golang.org/p/VjL4Tk7VwN)

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "errors"
    "runtime/debug"
    "time"
)

func f2() {
    panic(errors.New("oops")) // line 11
}

func f1() {
    defer func() {
        if e := recover(); e != nil {
            log.Printf("internal %s: %s", e, debug.Stack()) // line 20
        }
    }()
    f2() // line 15
}

func main() {
    defer func() {
        if e := recover(); e != nil {
            log.Printf("external %s: %s", e, debug.Stack()) // line 20
        } else {
            log.Println("Nothing to print")
        }
    }()

    go f1() // line 25

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
}
```

#### Lesser then two evils

Debug with [Delve](https://github.com/derekparker/delve) Or temporaly edit the package so it logs the full message (once understood you can revert the changes).

Also if you find the problem let the package author know so it can be fixed.